# Error when model diagnostics on stratified variable with coxph (survival package) in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival, cox

I have a dataset where 3 groups have recieved exposure to different media. One group is exposed to 1 of the 3 media. Therefore, my coxph model is stratified:

```
# My treatment variable is loaded as a factor.
fullModel <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ strata(treatment), data = d)
```

When I try to do model diagnostics I get this error:

```
test.assump <- cox.zph(fullModel)
Error in cox.zph(fullModel) : 
there are no score residuals for a Null model
```

But, if I remove the strata() argument, I get to run diagnostics on the model:

```
          chisq df    p
treatment  1.29  2 0.52
GLOBAL     1.29  2 0.52
```

I've made this example to reproduce my error:

```
data <- list(time=c(4,3,1,1,2,2,3,2,4,1,3,4), 
             status=c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1),  
             treatment=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2))

cox.test <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ strata(treatment), data = data)

test.coxas <- cox.zph(cox.test)
ggcoxzph(test.coxas)

ggcoxdiagnostics(test.coxas, type = "schoenfeld",
                 linear.predictions = F)
```

Should I do diagnostics without the strata argument? And then use the strata argument after so I can plot the different exposures in a ggsurvplot?
Where am I going wrong here?

Thank you in advance for helping me resolve this trouble.

Comment: `Should I do diagnostics without the strata argument?` - this question would get a better response on stat exchange, a sister site where you can ask statistics questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm bracketing whether using `strata()` is the best modeling choice, given what I understand of your application, and focusing on the actual question you asked.

Schoenfeld residuals are used to diagnose proportional hazard violations a Cox model's *covariates*.  Your model specification has no covariates.  Ergo, you have no PH violations to diagnose and potentially correct, which is why `cox.zph` is throwing a "null model" error, as in "this model only estimates the (Cox model's version of an) intercept term".

Put differently: Schoenfeld residuals are covariate-specific quantities, so if there are no covariates in the Cox model, there are no Schoenfelds to calculate. `cox.zph`'s calculations involve the Schoenfeld residuals, hence the error.

Instead, you have a `strata()` term.  Stratifying permits different groups to have a different baseline hazard rate (= the Cox's version of an intercept term, heuristically speaking).  There are many reasons you might stratify, but one of them is to *correct* for possible PH violations—the very issue that's leading you to run `cox.zph` in the first place.  If you keep stratifying on `treatment`, there are no PH-related model diagnostics for you to run.

(As an aside: for `ggcoxdiagnostics` in your MWE, you need to pass in the `coxph` object, not the `cox.zph` object.)